# WriteableBitmap in .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-functions, .net-standard, writeablebitmap

I have a working `ASP.NET WebAPI` which processes images, I'm trying to port the API over to `Azure Functions` (`.NET Standard 2.0`). I was able to migrate most of the functionality except one piece. I'm using `WriteableBitmap` to perform some manipulations on the image - it seems that the class is not available in .NET Standard 2.0. I get the following error message in Visual Studio 2017, but I can't add a reference to `PresentationCore` since it's not available at the references window.

```
The type 'WriteableBitmap' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

Has anyone experienced a similar problem or can help me out here?

//EDIT:
Here is the code which I use to create the `WriteableBitmap`

```
var width = array.Columns;
var height = array.Rows;
var rgbReverse = true;
var format = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
var channels = 3;
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, dpiX, dpiY, format, null);
```

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj i just updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

`WriteableBitmap` is part of WPF. It won't be available in core until dotnet core 3.0 (and I doubt it will be on azure functions).

If you want a dotnet standard 2d graphics api, I'd suggest [`ImageSharp`](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp)

You can do a lot with it, but you'll have to rewrite your manipulation code.

They have a samples respository with some [examples](https://github.com/SixLabors/Samples/tree/master/ImageSharp)